# Open new 'gnome-terminal' window with specific PS1 variable

Tags: command-line, gnome, bash, scripts

I'm pretty new to Linux, so thanks for taking the time to look at this. I'm simply trying to configure a script to open several new terminals, which works. The problem is that I would like to also color these terminals to my preferences.

I found a site with lots of information about this here:
[Color Bash prompt (ArchLinux Wiki)](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Color_Bash_Prompt)

This is the command I run in a live terminal, or via the script:

```
gnome-terminal --geometry 123x27+-10+14 -x PS1='\[\e[0;31m\]\u\[\e[m\] \[\e[1;34m\]\w\[\e[m\] \[\e[0;31m\]\$ \[\e[m\]\[\e[0;32m\]'
```

This is what it returns me:

```
Failed to execute child process "PS1='\[\e[0;31m\]\u\[\e[m\] \[\e[1;34m\]\w\[\e[m\] \[\e[0;31m\]\$ \[\e[m\]\[\e[0;32m\]'" (No such file or directory)
```

Just entering this command in a already running terminal seems to work fine:

```
PS1='\[\e[0;31m\]\u\[\e[m\] \[\e[1;34m\]\w\[\e[m\] \[\e[0;31m\]\$ \[\e[m\]\[\e[0;32m\]'
```

To circumvent this I was also trying to change my `/etc/bash.bashrc` file, but I had no luck with that modifying my default terminal color.

I understand that the Gnome Terminal has preferences that you can set for colors, but it is far more limited than the command I want to automatically run.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`bash` has `--rcfile file` option, that allows you to specify which config file to chose. It's not an uncommon thing for various profiles to be saved in various files, just consider `gnome-terminal` itself. I'd suggest you save couple of those custom `bashrc` files, and then call `gnome-terminal -e "bash --rcfile file"`

Example in the screenshot:

[image]